# Special numbers consecutive

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, arithmetic

A number is said special if it has two or more digits and is a multiple of the sum of its
digits.

(a) Find three consecutive special numbers.

(b) Find four consecutive special numbers.

Well, as I understand it, a special number is for example: $12$ is special because it's a multiple of $ 1 + 2 = 3$

Comment: Your understanding is correct. What other special numbers can you find?

Comment: @Clayton I could find several, but the problem is how to find formally, or generalize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://oeis.org/A060159

$110,111,112$

$510,511,512,513$

$131052,131053,131054,131055,131056$

are all "special numbers" (*more commonly called [Harshad or Niven numbers](http://oeis.org/A005349) in literature*)

C. N. Cooper and R. E. Kennedy proved [in a paper submitted to Fibonacci Quarterly in 1993](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/31-2/cooper.pdf) that there are not sequences of $21$ or more consecutive such numbers.

It is also known that there does exist sequences of $20$ consecutive of these numbers, the smallest *known* sequence of $20$ consecutive of these numbers being on the order of $10^{44363342786}$.  It is not yet known what the *smallest* possible such sequence of $20$ consecutive numbers is, but by the well ordering principle it must exist. [[$\dagger$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harshad_number#First_runs_of_exactly_n_consecutive_10-harshad_numbers)]

Even more generally, when considering these numbers represented instead in base $b$, [H. G. Grundman in 1994](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/32-2/grundman.pdf) extended this result to show that there cannot exist sequences of $2b+1$ consecutive numbers for any base $b$, which was later expanded on by [Brad Wilson](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/35-2/wilson.pdf) to show that there will however exist sequences of $2b$ consecutive numbers for any base $b$, which was later expanded on even further by T. Cai in 1996 to show that for $b=2$ or $b=3$ there are infinitely many such sequences.